# Significant delay when accessing internet via google cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

in our setup we have VM without external IPs accessing outside world via Google Cloud NAT.

We are observing strange behavior:

- every 10 - 15th request is significantly delayed (15 - 135 seconds)

```
  ~$ for i in {1..50}; do echo $i;  time curl -s 'https://stackoverflow.com/' > 
  /dev/null; done
  .
  .
  .
  15

  real  2m10.830s
  user  0m0.049s
  sys   0m0.029s
```

- I can see in the stackdriver logs that concerned connections were DROPPED:

```
    {
    .
    .
    .
      jsonPayload: {
        allocation_status: "DROPPED"
      }
      timestamp: "2019-09-20T11:41:05.904608023Z"  
    }
```

Any ideas/suggestions how to resolve the issue will be highly appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Boris

Comment: Does this happen on other sites? Smart firewall can detect that you are hitting the same page over and over and assume an attack is taking place. `DROPPED` means that the other side rejected your connection attempt. If that is the case, your solution is to not do that.

Comment: Issue is not specific to the site. It occurs even with sites we have in our control and we know that firewall rules do not apply.

Comment: its classic problem use GCP Cloud NAT, config "Minimum ports per VM instance" very torturous,

AWS NAT GATEWAY easy to use with minimun config ready for high traffic website, but for GCP Cloud NAT you need add more IP Public and config "Minimum ports per VM instance" for GCP Cloud NAT

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible your VMs are running out of [available NAT ports](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#number_of_nat_ports_and_connections). For example, if you allocate 4096 ports per VM, then you need a NAT IP address for every 15 VMs. During live operation if the VMs + NAT run out of available ports due to open connections (TCP being the longest lived) you may begin to see dropped traffic. You may want to consider reducing the [TCP timeout](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#nat_timeouts), or allocating more ports per VM.

You can see the current state of the NAT mapping (for example, number of ports per IP/VM) by using [this command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routers/get-nat-mapping-info) in the Cloud console:

gcloud compute routers get-nat-mapping-info [ROUTER NAME]

Answer (score 0):

You may want to also look into Endpoint-Independent Mapping:https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/ports-and-addresses#conflicts-eim

Frequent, recurring flows to Public endpoints are restricted by the Number of Ports/VM and also the Endpoint-Independent Mapping config. It would be useful if GCP allowed to change the NAT Delay Timer: https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview#nat_timeouts

At 256 Ports/VM, with 32 Public IP's on the NAT-GW, we calculated we could make 2.1 Requests/Second to the same (Destination-IP, Port, Protocol) tuple.